# Braintree fetch existing payment methods

Tags: ios, swift, braintree

Does anyone know how I can fetch all payment methods from a Braintree vault?

Using `BTDropInResult.fetch`, I can fetch the latest payment method, but not all. See below:

```
BTDropInResult.fetch(forAuthorization: clientToken, handler: { (result, error) in
    if (error != nil) {
        let message = error?.localizedDescription
        print (message)
    } else if let result = result {
        print(result) // latest payment method
    } else {
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact *support@braintreepayments.com*.</sub>

You can fetch all payment methods for a customer from the iOS client with `fetchPaymentMethodNonces` (or `fetchPaymentMethodNonces:completion`, which has an additional option, `defaultFirst`, to control whether the customer's default or their last used payment method is the first in the returned array). Both methods are documented here: http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/Braintree/4.7.5/Classes/BTAPIClient.html#//api/name/fetchPaymentMethodNonces.

These methods will only return payment methods if you have passed a customer ID in the client token used to instantiate the BTAPIClient object.